# AIX 7.1 missing Xm/Xm.h header

Tags: aix

I've written a sample c file which includes Xm/Xm.h. When compile it, I have the following error, "fatal error: Xm/Xm.h: No such file or directory"

I'm using AIX 7.1. What package do I need to install to fix this problem and where can I find it?  I was not able to find anything online regarding this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error message.

You need to install (with [installp on Aix](https://superuser.com/questions/701463/how-to-do-sudo-apt-get-on-an-aix-machine)):

- either openmotif (and openmotif-dev)
- or lesstif2-dev (smaller then openmotif, and can be enough)

(as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/219420))